# What instructions do hide the Status bar?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In an inherited Access app I have to maintain, there is a login screen (status bar at the bottom of Access window is still visible) then clicking "OK", the status bar disappears. What code should I search for finding (and removing) that behavior ?
I search the code for `SysCmd acSys`... but the instructions I found (`ClearStatus`, `SetStatus`, `InitMeter`)do not seems to do that.
I also searched for `Application.SetOption "Show Status Bar"` without success.
Any clue ?

Comment: Not sure, but why not just follow the login event and look through that procedure? I can't imagine a login procedure is that complex. Should jump right out at you.

Comment: what do you mean you searched for x? You mean in the inherited code or in help? `Application.SetOption "Show Status Bar", False` would certainly hide the status bar. If this isn't what is being done then I understand your problem in not understanding what is turning it off! As Jeremy Cook said, step through the procedure linked to the OK button - it should be apparent what is happening.

Comment: I did not step through the code because it's huge.

Comment: The login event code is huge? (you only have to look at what happens after the OnClick event of the OK button, I can't imagine it's that many lines of code to got through)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
Application.SetOption "Show Status Bar", False
```

This is the code that hides or shows the status bar, depending on whether you enter true or false for the final argument.  If you haven't found it yet, go into code view and search for "Status Bar" by using the ctrl+f search function.  If you don't find it in the login form, it is probably in the form that is opening after login. I personally use this code in the On Open/On Activate functions in my "Home" form that opens after the user logs in.